# How can this complex command be broken down and explained for someone starting with Tex?

Tags: macros, datatool, protected-macro

I got this Tex command, as a [solution to a different problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609949/is-there-an-equivalent-of-datatools-dtlifhaskey-for-value) and it works. But I have trouble understanding the details of how it works since I'm not that proficient in Latex coding and I want to learn.

```
%\DTLfetchifnull{<db name>}%
%               {<column1 name>}%
%               {<column1 value>}%
%               {<column2 name>}%
%               {<tokens in case <column2-value> is not a null-value>}%
%               {<tokens in case <column2-value> is a null-value>}%
%               {<tokens in case <column1-value> does not exist>}%
%
% Both with <tokens in case <column2-value> is not a null-value> and with
% <tokens in case <column2-value> is a null-value> the macro
% \dtlcurrentvalue is defined to yield the value of the column whose name
% is <column2 name>.
%
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{NewDocumentCommand}%
{\newcommand\DTLfetchifnull[7]}%
{\NewDocumentCommand\DTLfetchifnull{mmmmmmm}}%
{%
  \begingroup%
    \protected@edef\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue{%
        \noexpand%
  \endgroup
  \noexpand\dtlgetrowindex{\noexpand\dtl@rowidx}{#1}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}}{#3}%
  }\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue%
  \ifx \dtl@rowidx\dtlnovalue%
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
  \else%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
  \fi%
  {%
    \edtlgetrowforvalue{#1}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}}{#3}%
    \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\dtlcurrentvalue}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#4}}%
    \DTLifnull{\dtlcurrentvalue}{#6}{#5}% 
  }{%
    #7%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
```

- The \makeatletter ... \makeatother as I understand is necessary, because we change something fundamental about NewDocumentCommand and newcommand?
- @ifundefined{NewDocumentCommand}% as I understand makes it possible to use NewDocumentCommand instead of newcommand without \usepackage{xparse}?

Why do we need this? Can we just use \usepackage{xparse} and skip the whole:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{NewDocumentCommand}%
{\newcommand\DTLfetchifnull[7]}%
...
\makeatother
```

Or is there an advantage in doing this way?

- \begingroup ... \endgroup as I understand is something like '{ }' but with different behavior
- but it enclosed "\protected@edef@dtl@dogetrowforvalue{" so the "}" is outside, how does that work?

  \begingroup%
  \protected@edef@dtl@dogetrowforvalue{%
  \noexpand%
  \endgroup
  \noexpand\dtlgetrowindex{\noexpand\dtl@rowidx}{#1}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}}{#3}%
  }@dtl@dogetrowforvalue%

I find it very hard to read how these functions are encapsulated and to decide what is an argument of which function or just following after a function.

This says check if(\dtl@rowidx\dtlnovalue) do \expandafter@secondoftwo else \expandafter@firstoftwo.

```
  \ifx \dtl@rowidx\dtlnovalue
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
```

Are @firstoftwo and @secondoftwo the two options in curly braces that are coming after this?

Comment: you surely can simply load xparse (or not if you know your latex is current enough) and drop the test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer One of my computers still runs Win95 and MiKTeX 2.4. I installed datatool and some other packages manually. xparse is not installed there and I am too lazy to do that. So I prefer the test. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are needed in order to allow using command names with `@` in them. There is nothing really special about it.

The first idea is to use `\NewDocumentCommand{\DTLfetchifnull}{mmmmmmm}` if it is available, otherwise the standard `\newcommand{\DTLfetchifnull}[7]` is used (for compatibility with older documents).

With newer releases we essentially get

```
\NewDocumentCommand\DTLfetchifnull{mmmmmmm}
{%
  \begingroup%
    \protected@edef\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue{%
        \noexpand%
  \endgroup
  \noexpand\dtlgetrowindex{\noexpand\dtl@rowidx}{#1}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}}{#3}%
  }\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue%
  \ifx \dtl@rowidx\dtlnovalue%
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
  \else%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
  \fi%
  {%
    \edtlgetrowforvalue{#1}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}}{#3}%
    \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\dtlcurrentvalue}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#4}}%
    \DTLifnull{\dtlcurrentvalue}{#6}{#5}% 
  }{%
    #7%
  }%
}%
```

that shows not really good programming style. For instance, there are several useless `%`, but they're not harmful, just annoying. Also the first `\noexpand` is useless, because `\endgroup is not expandable. I'd write it as

```
\NewDocumentCommand\DTLfetchifnull{mmmmmmm}
{%
  \begingroup
    \protected@edef\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue{%
  \endgroup
  \noexpand\dtlgetrowindex{\noexpand\dtl@rowidx}{#1}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}}{#3}%
  }\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue
  \ifx \dtl@rowidx\dtlnovalue
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
  {%
    \edtlgetrowforvalue{#1}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}}{#3}%
    \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\dtlcurrentvalue}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#4}}%
    \DTLifnull{\dtlcurrentvalue}{#6}{#5}% 
  }{%
    #7%
  }%
}
```

If an older LaTeX release, the first line would be `\newcommand{\DTLfetchifnull}[7]`.

The idea is to define `\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue` to yield

```
\endgroup
\dtlgetrowindex{\dtl@rowidx}
  {expansion of #1}
  {expansion of \dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}}
  {expansion of #3}
```

and then the scratch macro `\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue` will be executed, which will assign a meaning to `\dtl@rowidx`, which *can* be `\dtlnovalue` (depending on the arguments `#1`, `#2` and `#3`. The initial `\endgroup` will balance the already digested `\begingroup` and the definition of `\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue` will be forgotten as soon as `\endgroup` is executed (but the expansion of `\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue` has already been placed on the input stream, so there is no problem with undefining it).

Next the token is compared with `\dtlnovalue`. The construction

```
\if<something>
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\fi
{tokens A}
{tokens B}
```

is very common in LaTeX programming. If the test returns true, `tokens B` will be used, otherwise `tokens A`.

So, if `\dtl@rowidx` turns out to be `\dtlnovalue`, the argument `#7` will be used. Otherwise it will be some legal row index and

```
\edtlgetrowforvalue{#1}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}}{#3}%
\dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\dtlcurrentvalue}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#4}}%
\DTLifnull{\dtlcurrentvalue}{#6}{#5}%
```

will be used. Finding out what *this* does needs studying the manual of `datatool`.

Comment: Nice, thank you. The annoying % are probably my fault, dissecting the code into more lines. The datatool functions at the end I understand. The rest you explained well.

Comment: Why is % used at the end of some lines and not on others here? What is the purpose?

Comment: To suppress extra space ("glue") ending up in the output. e.g., newline character. Try an experiment to see.

Comment: @TheMindWithin The annoying `%` do not come from me/my code. The unneeded `\noexpand` before `\endgroup`, which is not expandable,  indeed is bad programming style and does come from my code, but I spotted it and therefore edited my code and removed it _before_ you posted this question. I should have notified you about that edit, e.g., via a comment. Please accept my apologies for not doing so.

Comment: @egreg +1 I should have been the one to explain the code, because I am the perpetrator who committed writing it. :-) Thank you very much for doing it for me. :-)

Comment: @Cicada TeX reads input linew-ise and tokenizes character-wise. After reading a line all space-characters at the right end of the line are removed and a character is appended whose character-code equals the value of the parameter `\endlinechar`. Usually `\endlinechar` is 13, denoting the carriage-return-character, which in turn usually has category code 5 (end of line) and therefore yields a) no token at all if the reading-apparatus is in state "skipping blanks" b) an explicit character-token of charcode 32 and catcode 10(space) if in state "middle of line"  c) the token `\par` if in state

Comment: @Cicada c) the token `\par` if in state "new line".  `\newlinechar` is a parameter denoting the character-code of character-tokees which trigger continuing writing at the begin of a new line when TeX is writing tokens to external file, e.g., .log-file, or to open `\write`-register or terminal.  Besides carriage-return-character, there is a linefeed-character both in ASCII and in Unicode. But "newline character" seems like misleading terminology to me.

Comment: @egreg for compatibility with older **documents** <-> for compatibility with older **TeX-installations**

Comment: @TheMindWithin If you look at the definition of `\edtlgetrowforvalue` via `\show\edtlgetrowforvalue` you will find that it expands to code which is very similar to `\protected@edef\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue...`  . :-)